# How to replace part of a string with anchors

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert some string to html. Just like this

```
let str = 'lorem ipsum [google website]="https://google.com" lorem ipsum [facebook website]="https://facebook.com"'

convert(str)
```

expected output:

```
lorem ipsum <a href="https://google.com">google website</a> lorem ipsum <a href="https://facebook.com">facebook website</a>
```

P.S i'm using reactjs

Comment: What kind of html? Do you need to add to anchor tag's `href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular expressions and `string.replace(regex, replaceWith)`.
`$1`, `$2` are capture groups (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n))

```js
let re = /\[(.+?)\]="(.+?)"/g
let str = 'lorem ipsum [google website]="https://google.com" lorem ipsum [facebook website]="https://facebook.com"';
let newStr = str.replace(re, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
document.write(newStr);
```

Comment: This is really usefull!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will only match valid url:

```
function convert(string){
  console.log(string.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]="((https?|ftp):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?)"/ig, "<a href='\$2'>$1</a>"));
}
convert('lorem ipsum [google]=https://google.com lorem ipsums lorem [facebook]=https://facebook.com ipsum lorem')
```